# Creating new accounts using `web3`

Tags: go-ethereum, web3.py, rpc, eip

In the new version of `web3.py`, the `personal.newAccount` functionality has been retained only for the `geth` client.

What is the right cross-client approach to creating new accounts?

See [v5 migration](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/v5_migration.html) and [new RPC spec](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/pull/1474).